# QML ListView height with multiple nested models

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` with a simple model which in turn also has a model which is actually displayed:

```
ListView {
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("ListView height: " + height)
    model: ["1"]
    delegate: Column {
        Component.onCompleted: console.log("Inner delegate height: " + height)
        Repeater {
            model: ["A", "B"]
            delegate: Text {
                Component.onCompleted: console.log("Text height: " + height)
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the `Text` and the `Column` height. Even though `ListModel` knows the `Column` height, it still has zero height.

My question is: how to properly assign `ListView` the given size?

The program outputs:

```
qml: Text height: 14
qml: Text height: 14
qml: Inner delegate height: 28
qml: ListView height: 0
```

Comment: I don't think `ListView` adjusts its height to fit content. Since `ListView` derived from `Flickable` it have to be `contentHeight`, not `height`. So you have to set size of `ListView` manually, with anchors or layouts

Comment: By the way, why using `ListView` here? Just put the `Column` in a `Flickable`. Shorter, simpler code with the same visual outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Inspired by them, I expanded the code and posted it below.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo: in the real-world scenario I need many nested loops and I think implementing the solution with a `ListView` will be easier. The example in the question was a bit unfortunate to show only one item, `1`, in the outer model.

Comment: I see. Well, I've underestimated the problem and that's my fault. Good to know that you solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @folibis' suggestion, I changed the `contentHeight` and `contentWidth` properties when the delegate's `height` or `width` changes. After adding `anchors` to `ListView`, it perfectly works together with the encompassing item.

Here is the code:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: ["1", "2"]
    delegate: Column {
        onHeightChanged: ListView.view.contentHeight = height
        onWidthChanged: ListView.view.contentWidth = width
        Repeater {
            model: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
            delegate: Text {
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inspired by @BaCaRoZzo's comment, if one would not need a `ListView`, the problem can solved without it:

```
Flickable {
    id: flickable
    anchors.fill: parent
    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: ["1", "2"]
            Column {
                onHeightChanged: flickable.contentHeight = height
                onWidthChanged: flickable.contentWidth = width
                Repeater {
                    model: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                    delegate: Text {
                        text: modelData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```